# What are possible reasons for a sympy integration running "forever"?

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-integration

I had the following code, which defines a simple function taking two real variables as arguments and returning a complex number. The function call would not return in a minute's time. I determined the cause was inappropriate us of sympify (see below)

```
%%time
from sympy import *

x,t=symbols('x t') # <-- symbols('x t', real=True)
e_psi_sw=sin(2*pi*x) + exp(1j*t)*sin(pi*x) # exp(I*t) <-- exp(1j*t)
pdf=conjugate(e_psi_sw)*e_psi_sw
integrate(pdf*x,(x,0,1))  # <-- no problem
```

Comment: Can you explain (using test code) what you mean by "subs() method not working and lambda functions for plotting not working"?  You need [`lambdify`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/lambdify.html) to convert the sympy result to a numpy function and to plot with matplotlib. To plot using sympy, just call `res = integrate(....); plot(res)`

Comment: Since you did not show how you were using `sympify` it is not possible for others to see what was giving problems. But with the changes indicated by `<--`, the result is obtained  quickly and simplies to `-(16*exp(2*I*t) - 9*pi**2*exp(I*t) + 16)*exp(-I*t)/(18*pi**2)`

Answer (score 1):

It's faster if you use sympy's `I` instead of the complex Python float `1j`. It is generally best to avoid using floats unnecessarily in sympy.

Also declaring the symbols x and t to be real results in a simpler integrand that can be integrated more easily.

Answer (score 0):

I was calling sympify with a string rather than a bare expression. When I removed the quotation marks, the integral ran quickly and the other issues I cited here were also resolved.

I did change j to I also...